# simple slopes for planned contrasts

Tags: r, emmeans

With this example data set

```
dat <- data.frame(sample=c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 7,8,9,10,11,12), 
                  esteem=c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                  condition=factor(c("a", "a", "a", "a","b", "b", "b", "b","c", "c", "c", "c")),
                  scores=c(2,4,3,5,6,13,41,30,30,23,24,24))

mod <- lm(scores~esteem*condition, data=dat)
```

I am doing planned contrasts and my set up is this:

1. comparing the condition A vs. condition B and C combined
2. comparing the condition B vs. C.

The contrast looks like this:

```
contrasts1 <- c(-2,1,1) #A vs. B and C
contrasts2 <-c(0,-1,1) #B vs. C
contrasts(dat$condition) <- cbind(contrasts1, contrasts2)
dat$condition
```

This will produce

```
[1] a a a a b b b b c c c c
attr(,"contrasts")
  contrasts1 contrasts2
a         -2          0
b          1         -1
c          1          1
Levels: a b c
```

Typically, with categorical x continuous variable interaction, I would get simple slopes of a continuous variable at each categorical level using emtrends,

```
emmeans::emtrends(mod, pairwise ~ condition, var="esteem")
```

This gives me the slope of esteem at condition A, the slope of esteem at condition B, and the slope of esteem at condition C.

```
$emtrends
 condition esteem.trend   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 a                 0.80 1.98  6    -4.06     5.66
 b                -6.24 1.08  6    -8.87    -3.60
 c                -1.70 1.98  6    -6.56     3.16

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

However, I have a contrast that compares condition A vs. B and C and is there a way to get the slope of esteem for the combined condition B and C using emtrends or other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. You do it the same way as for contrasting marginal means:

```
> (EMT <- emtrends(mod, ~ condition, var = "esteem"))
 condition esteem.trend   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 a                 0.80 1.98  6    -4.06     5.66
 b                -6.24 1.08  6    -8.87    -3.60
 c                -1.70 1.98  6    -6.56     3.16

Confidence level used: 0.95 

> contrast(EMT, list(`a.vs.bc` = c(1, -.5, -.5), `b.vs.c` = c(0, 1, -1)), adjust = "bonf")
 contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 a.vs.bc      4.77 2.28  6   2.088  0.1636
 b.vs.c      -4.54 2.26  6  -2.009  0.1826

P value adjustment: bonferroni method for 2 tests 

> ### or, if you want just the first one:
> contrast(EMT, "trt.vs.ctrl", ref = c("b", "c"))
 contrast     estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 a - avg(b,c)     4.77 2.28  6   2.088  0.0818
```

See [the vignette on contrasts](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html) for more examples

Comment: Note: This works the same regardless of how you coded the `contrasts` attribute in `dat`.

Comment: thank you so much for your response. I really appreciate it. It is not quite what I am looking for (I am trying to look for esteem.trend for 'bc', just as how esteem-trend was produced for a, b, c automatically).

Comment: Well,  I guess I'm not sure what you want, but `EMT` has estimates of those slopes, and you can compute any contrast (or other linear combination) of them via `contrast()`, and it doesn't matter how you coded the regression model.

Comment: Like, do you want the average of the slopes for B and for C? -- `contrast(EMT, list(bc.avg = c(0, .5, .5))`